# SignByCert private key password

Tags: sql-server, signature

So, given MS SQL 2008R2 or better:

I want to not only store data in a table but be able for my application to automatically verify it was not modified.

Solution seems to be to use SignByCert to make a digital signature of every cell and insert each result into a matching table full of signatures so I can call VerifySignedByCert later when I query it to see if someone changed the plaintext data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/signbycert-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/verifysignedbycert-transact-sql

My question is, signbycert wants an optional password to decrypt the private key it is signing with. I don't want to store private key passpharses in my stored procedures that call SignByCert. It doesn't seem to make sense to just leave the passphrases in the clear.

Alternatively, is there a secure (good) way to reference the passphrase or is there a safe way to store or NOT encrypt the private key in MS SQL so MS SQL hides the passphrase and knows it internally so I don't have to put it in the SQL statement?

Comment: My solution to this problem thus far has been to store a persisted public/private key pair in the Windows Certificate Store. I use  Cryptographic Next Generation to sign using the private part of the key and the public part of the key to verify signatures. So for each column, I hash the column data with a SHA1 hash and make a signature using that hash and the private key as inputs and return a signature. I insert the signature in with the raw data into the database. When I query the data I can verify it hasn't been changed by hashing it, passing in the hash, the signature and public key.